# Detect Encoding with Java

Tags: java

I have an example which is workingfine. With this example (provided below),  I can detect the encoding of file using the universaldetector framework from mozilla.

But I want that this example to detect the encoding of input and not of the file for Example using class `Scanner`? How can I modify the code below to detect the encoding of input instead of file?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector;

public class TestDetector {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];


    java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\khalat\\Desktop\\Java\\toti.txt");


    // (1)
    UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

    // (2)
    int nread;
    while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
      detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
    }

    // (3)
    detector.dataEnd();

    // (4)
    String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
    if (encoding != null) {
      System.out.println("Detected encoding = " + encoding);
    } else {
      System.out.println("No encoding detected.");
    }

    // (5)
    detector.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "of input" when you haven't shown any other input...

Comment: How would a `Scanner` work? The `Scanner` is a `char` input not a `byte` input - by the time the `Scanner` reads something, the encoding is already set.

Comment: @BoristheSpider oh. Oops.

Comment: hello,i want to detect the econding of Input-Scanner und not form File input.

Comment: The detection of charset in this way is a _destructive_ process. The analysis reads the stream. I'm not sure how you intend to use that on STDIN. Further, reading from an `InputSteam` is a blocking operation - it is very likely that unless you have piped a file to STDIN your program will just block indefinitely if you tried to read STDIN in this way, and in that case you could analyse the file directly.

Comment: ok.. do have any idea how i can detect the input encoding..??

Comment: What makes you think it isn't the platform default?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand u? what did u mean? i need a programm writing in java wich can detect the charachter encoding? for example when i input russian chrachter then should be displaying iso-8859-5 etc....

Comment: What makes you think your Russian character isn't in UTF-8?

Comment: yes i know but the Problem the SAP-System accept only iso-8859-1 and i want to make sure that input data corresponds only this ISO-8859-1.. u understand what i mean... and now im looking for framework wich can help me ... i thick whit charset from  Java can't do that... do u know maybe ontoher frame like apache tika??

Answer (score 0):

i found a elegant example wich can test at least, wether the charatcht is ISO-8859-1 see code below.

```
public class TestIso88591 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(TestIso88591.testISO("ü")){
            System.out.println("True");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("False");
        }

    }
    public static boolean testISO(String text){
        return  Charset.forName(CharEncoding.ISO_8859_1).newEncoder().canEncode(text);
    }
}
```

now i hav question to expert Java .there is a posibillity to test charachter wether it is ISO-8859-5 or ISO-8859-7? yes yes I know there is utf-8 but my exact question its how can i test the iso-8859-5 charachter. because the input data should be stored in SAP and SAP can handel only with ISO-8859-1 CHarachter. I need that as soon as.

Answer (score -1):

OK I researched a bit more. And the result is. It is useless to read bytes from stdin to guess the encoding, because the java API let you directly read the input as a string which is already encoded ;) The only usecase for this dector is when you get a stream of unknown bytes from a file or socket etc. to guess how to decode it in a java string.

Next pseudo code, it's only theoretical approach to it. But as we figured out it makes no sense ;)

Its very simple.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\khalat\\Desktop\\Java\\toti.txt");

UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

int nread;
while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
    detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
}
```

What you are doing here is reading from the file into an byte array, which is then passed to the detector.

Replace your FileInputStream with an other reader.

For example to read everything from Standard In:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

int nread = 0;
while ((nread = isr.read(buf, nread, buf.length)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
    detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
}
```

ATTENTION!!
This code is not tested by me. Its only based in Java API Docs.
I also would place a BufferedReader between the input stream and the read, to puffer. Also it can't work because of the size of the buffer with 4096 bytes. As I see my Example  it would work, when you directly enter minimum 4096 bytes in Stdandard IN in one chunk, otherwise the while loop will never start.

About Reader API, The Base class java.io.Reader (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read(char[],%20int,%20int)) Defines the method read as abstract, and any Reader based impl. has to impl this method. SO IT IS THERE!!!

About you can't figure out the encoding of a chunk of unknown bytes. Yes thats right. But you can make a guess, like the detector from mozilla tries. Because you have some clues: 1. We expect that the bytes are a text 2. we know any byte in any specified encoding 3. we can trie to decode several bytes in a guessed encoding and compare the resulting string

About we are experts:
Yes most of use are ones ;) But we don't like to make the homework for someone else. We like to fix bugs or give advices. So provide a full example which provides an error we can fix. Or as it happend here: we give you an advice with some pseudo code. (I don't have the time to setup a project and write you an working example)

Nice comment thread ;)

Comment: # rmertins its show me a errro no suitable method found for read(byte[],int,int)?? what should i do. Thanx

Comment: A `Reader`,  for example an `InputStreamReader`, does not read `byte`. There is no method to read `byte` on a `Reader`.

Comment: @Boris.. and how i can solv this Problem?

Comment: @adilos804 evidently no-one has any idea what you are trying to do. Clarify the question.

Comment: @ Boris i thought here are just the experts

Comment: Hello Expert... im waiting for your help.. Thanx in Advanced??

Comment: @ boris its very simple... instead of file path i want to input a String... i hope its clearly for u

Comment: @adilos804 you cannot detect the encoding of a `String`. A `String` has no encoding (well it does, `UTF-16`, but that's neither here nor there). A `byte[]` has an encoding, this is the conversion table to use when converting the bytes to a `String`. Again, what you are trying to do makes no sense to anyone. Clarify the question. Preferably _in the question_ not in comments on a random answer.

Comment: @Boris what should happen on a windows system, when you read the std. in as bytes and tries to figure out the encoding? I believer here in western europe (where I am) it will make a guess about CP1252 (Windows Latin1) :) Yes you are right, a String in Java has no encoding anymore, because java knows himself to handle the encoding in the jvm.

Comment: @ rmertins im waiting for your suggestion here in this forum not anymore i know her is only expert java which can giv me best advice.

it would be nice of you if you can give me suggestions how I can detect the ecoding af input string. Maybe there is a framework? i search in google but t didn't found any good result.

Thanx Expert Java ;)

Comment: As everyone already told you. When it is already a String a Java you don't need to guess the encoding, its usless. Java already handled that for you. Only when writing that string in an output you can define an encoding. Guessing the encoding of an input is only usefull when it is an unknown chunkg of bytes coming from an unknown source. In any other case the environment should give you informations about the encoding.